# ConTeXt: Map 'ß' to 'ss' in indices

Tags: context, indexing

**Problem**

In historical German some words can be written with both 'ß' and 's', e.g. "Erkenntniß" and "Erkenntnis".

Since I want to depict these different variants in my index, I use both `\index{Erkenntnis}` and `\index{Erkenntniß}`:

```
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]

\defineregister[custom]
\setupregister[custom]
  [compress=yes,
   indicator=no,
   pagestyle=\tf,
   n=1]

\starttext

In historischer Schreibung sind \custom{Erkenntniß}Erkenntniß 
und \custom{Erkenntnis}Erkenntnis identisch.

\page

In historischer Schreibung sind \custom{Erkenntnis}Erkenntnis 
und \custom{Erkenntniß}Erkenntniß identisch.

\page

\placecustom

\stoptext
```

But since 'ß' is mapped to 's' instead of 'ss' (which is more common), "Erkenntniß" and "Erkenntnis" are mixed up in the index:

[image: mixture of two terms]

---

**Question**

What can I do to have two separate entries for these terms, i.e. map 'ß' to 'ss'? I already tried to configure sort-lan.lua, but that didn't yield any results and the sorting remained the same.

I also noticed that the mapping of 'ß' to 'ss' is somehow suppressed in lang-ini.lua, but since I'm pretty new to Lua I don't know whether or how I should change this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely not nice.  The code below is relying on the specific layout of the replacements table in [`sort-lan.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/f923c957a3b322ae3ee8e7a0b20df1580869bee7/tex/context/base/mkiv/sort-lan.lua#L96-L104).

```lua
definitions['de']    = {
    parent = 'default',
    replacements = {
        { "ä", 'ae' }, { "Ä", 'Ae' },
        { "ö", 'oe' }, { "Ö", 'Oe' },
        { "ü", 'ue' }, { "Ü", 'Ue' },
        { "ß", 's'  },
    },
}
```

As you can count, the character we want to replace is the second in the seventh subtable, i.e. `sorters.definitions["de"].replacements[7][2] = "ss"`.

```
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]

\defineregister[custom]
\setupregister[custom]
  [compress=yes,
   indicator=no,
   pagestyle=\tf,
   n=1]

\startluacode
sorters.definitions["de"].replacements[7][2] = "ss"
\stopluacode

\starttext

In historischer Schreibung sind \custom{Erkenntniß}Erkenntniß 
und \custom{Erkenntnis}Erkenntnis identisch.

\page

In historischer Schreibung sind \custom{Erkenntnis}Erkenntnis 
und \custom{Erkenntniß}Erkenntniß identisch.

\page

\placecustom

\stoptext
```

[image]

If you don't want to rely on the fact that the ß/s replacement is in place number seven, you could also explicitly search for it using

```lua
for _,v in pairs(sorters.definitions["de"].replacements) do
   local char = unpack(v)
   if char == "ß" then
       v[2] = "ss"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I accessed the table directly (without searching for the entry), and everything works as it should.

Comment: @meliade I think it might be a good idea to guard the direct access in some way, e.g. `if sorters.definitions["de"].replacements[7][1] == "ß" then sorters.definitions["de"].replacements[7][2] = "ss" else error("BOOM!") end` so that you are “notified” if the table layout changes.